# how to access the id of div which is loaded through ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have button with id = new which loads the new page

```
$("#new").click(function(){
$('#message_area').load('new.php');
});
```

There is a button in new.php which sends message to database. But i have a problem with it , it only works for first time when page loads if i navigate to some other links via ajax and again load new.php using above code then send button in new.php does not work i have to refresh the page then it works. I think its because the send button in new.php is added after DOM is created for first time  .
Please help Thanks in advance ..

Comment: thanks for all the comments and answer but my problem is not solved yet here is code for new.php <div id="message_area>"<div id="message_body">



<h3><label for="to">To :</label><input type="text" name="to" id="to" size="50" maxlength="50" /></h3>

<div id="message_content">
<textarea cols="80" id="message" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="message_send">
<input type="button" class="blue_button" id="send_msg" value="Send Message" /><div id="message_report"></div>
</div>
</div> here id="send_msg" dont work when new.php is loaded second time after accessing another link via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//jquery >= v1.7
$("body").on('click', '#new', function(){
    $('#message_area').load('new.php');
});

//jquery < v1.7
$("#new").live('click',function(){
    $('#message_area').load('new.php');
});
```

Comment: Your `.on` example will not behave in the same way as your `.live` example. You need to delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree. Also note that `delegate` is preferred to `live` when `on` is not available (unless you're using a really old version).

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed the page :)

Comment: @Dutchie432 why have used body can you please explain in jquery>=1.7

Comment: Well, for the `on` function, you can think of the selector as the scope under which this applies. So, in my example, the code would execute any time an item with the id `new` is clicked inside of the `body` tag. Mine is a simplified example - check out http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

You will need to post more details of your markup for a more accurate answer, but the general idea is to use event delegation. Bind the event handler to an ancestor of the button that does not get removed from the DOM. For example:

```
$("#message_area").on("click", "#yourButton", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This works because DOM events bubble up the tree, through all of an elements ancestors. Here you are simply capturing the event higher up the tree and checking if it originated from something you are interested in (`#yourButton`).

See jQuery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more. Note that if you're using a version of jQuery below 1.7, you will need to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#new").live("click", function(){
$('#message_area').load('new.php');
});
```

just realized this was deprecated-- should be using on instead.. my bad.

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` instead, and if you're using an older version of jQuery (< 1.7) use `delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

To manage dynamically created elements like this, you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7 and above) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (jQuery 1.4.3 and above) to assign the events.  Seems everyone has beaten me to the code, but I'll post this for the links to the functions.